# Find the derivative of the inverse of this real function $f(x) = 2x + \cos(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I don't know how to attack this problem. The last I've tried is using a differential equation, but I don't know how to solve it.

Let $y$ be $f^{-1}(x)$. Knowing that $x=f(y)= 2y + \cos(y)$ and derivating I obtained the following non-linear first order differential equation: $y' \cdot (2-\sin(y))=1$

I would thank you if you can help me.

Edit: I haven't said, but it is trivial to check that the function is injective, so it has an inverse, because $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ $f'(x) \neq0$

Comment: There's a typo in the derivative, I think it should be $y' · (2 - \sin(y)) = 1$. You can try solving the differential equation now, it seems more easy as before.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So stupid from my part, sorry. But how could I solve the differential equation, anyway?

Comment: Perhaps the answer that you're expected to provide is that $$(f^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{2 - \sin f^{-1}(x)}$$. (That's what I'd be asking for if *I* had asked the question.)

Comment: @JohnHughes No, I want a explicit form of the funtion. Not in terms of the inverse function.

Comment: Hmm I think John Hughes is right, I think the inverse of this function cannot be written explicitly

Comment: Alas, in that case I don't think I can help, but I look forward to seeing someone else solve this one!

Comment: See [inverse functions and differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given function 
$$ y= 2 x + \cos x \tag{1} $$
Inverse function
$$ x = 2y + \cos y \tag{2}$$
Differentiating with respect to $x$
$$ 1 = 2 y^{'}  - \sin y \, y^{'} $$
$$  y^{'} = \dfrac{1}{2-\sin y} $$

Cannot be further put in terms of $x$ as (1) and (2) are transcendental.

Comment: $x = 2y + \cos y$ ?

Comment: Yes, what is the problem with it?